# Flutter TabBarView and BottomNavigationBar pages are not refreshing with SetState

Tags: flutter, setstate, tabbar, bottomnavigationview

I have the following Flutter BottomNavigationBar, I have 3 children page widgets. As soon as the user writes a review and press the submit button, I am calling the void _clear() which resets the values in the textfield widgets. This method is inside and called from the WriteReview widget but is not working, the screen is not refreshing. The data it self is being reset but the UI has not be refreshed. I tried with and without setState(){ _clear()}; but no results.

I have similar issue with the TabBarView. What I would expect as a result would be the selected widget page to be refreshed.

I assume is something different on how the widgets are being handled in the TabBarView and BottomNavigationBar that I am missing.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeViewState createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  final String _writeReviewLabel = 'Write review';
  final String _searchLabel = 'Search';
  final String _accountLabel = 'Account';

  var _currentIndex = 0;

  final List<Widget> _bottomBarItems = [
    WriteReviewView(),
    SearchView(),
    UserAccountView()
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final accentColor = Theme.of(context).accentColor;
    final primaryColor = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;
    return BaseView<HomePresenter>(
      createPresenter: () => HomePresenter(),
      onInitialize: (presenter) {
        _currentIndex = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
      },
      builder: (context, child, presenter) => Scaffold(
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            backgroundColor: primaryColor,
            selectedItemColor: accentColor,
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
            elevation: 0,
            currentIndex: _currentIndex,
            onTap: (index) {
              onTabTapped(index, presenter);
            },
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                activeIcon: Icon(Icons.rate_review),
                icon: Icon(Icons.rate_review),
                title: Text(_writeReviewLabel),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                activeIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                title: Text(_searchLabel),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  activeIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                  icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                  title: Text(_accountLabel)),
            ],
          ),
          body: _bottomBarItems[_currentIndex]),
    );
  }

  void onTabTapped(int index, HomePresenter presenter) {
    if (index == _currentIndex) {
      return;
    }

    if (presenter.isAuthenticated) {
      setState(() {
        _currentIndex = index;
      });
    } else {
      presenter.pushNamed(context, Routes.login, arguments: () {
        if (presenter.isAuthenticated) {
          Future.delayed(const Duration(microseconds: 500), () {
            setState(() {
              _currentIndex = index;
            });
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Write Review View

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'base/BaseView.dart';

class WriteReviewView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WriteReviewViewState createState() => _WriteReviewViewState();
}

class _WriteReviewViewState extends State<WriteReviewView> {
  final String _locationLabel = 'Location';
  final String _reviewLabel = 'Review';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BaseView<WriteReviewPresenter>(
        createPresenter: () => WriteReviewPresenter(),
        onInitialize: (presenter) {
          presenter.init();
        },
        builder: (context, child, presenter) => Container(
              color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
              child: _body(presenter),
            ));
  }

  Widget _body(WriteReviewPresenter presenter) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraint) {
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: constraint.maxHeight),
          child: IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Card(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 8.0),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 20),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Icon(Icons.location_on,
                                  color: Theme.of(context).cursorColor),
                              SectionTitle(_locationLabel),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        ChooseAddressButton(presenter.addressContainer.address, () {
                          presenter.navigateNewAddress(context);
                        }),
                        SizedBoxes.medium,
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Card(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 8.0),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Icon(Icons.star, color: Theme.of(context).indicatorColor),
                              SectionTitle(_reviewLabel),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBoxes.medium,
                        CustomTextFormField(
                            data: presenter.reviewContainer.review,
                            showMinimum: true,
                            characterLimit: 50,
                            maxLines: 4,
                            height: 100),
                        ModifyRatingBar(50.0, presenter.reviewContainer.rating, false),
                        Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                            child: Divider(indent: 40, endIndent: 40)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                  child: Card(
                    color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                    child: FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        _submit(context, presenter);
                      },
                      child: Text('Submit',style:TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 18,color: Colors.white)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  void _submit(BuildContext context, WriteReviewPresenter presenter) async {
    LoadingPopup.show(context);

    final status = await presenter.submit(context);

    LoadingPopup.hide(context);

    if (status == ReviewStatus.successful) {
      PostCompletePopup.show(context);
      setState(() {
        presenter.clear();
      });
    } else {
      presenter.showError(context, status);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`setState()` only refreshes the widget that called it, and all the widgets under it.

When calling `setState()`from `WriteReview` widget, it will not update the `HomeView` widget. Try moving the `setState()`call to the `HomeView` widget using some sort of callback.

Comment: So the fact that WriteReview is part of the HomeView as element of the BottomNavigationBarItem, gives the responsibility to the home view to update its children UI? 

Isn't this counter intuitive comparing the rest of the project? In all other cases set state is updating the calling widget as intended.

I want to understand why on TabBarView and BottomBarNavigation page children the setstate is not working, its a special rule for those controllers?

Comment: i may have understood incorrectly. can you share the code thats not working in the writereview widget?

Comment: I updated my initial post, the method in the end _submit is the one with the issue, the call "presenter.clear()"  just sets strings to empty and rating bar value to 0. I added debug logs and the values actually change, although the UI doesn't reflect that change.

I tried to wrap it inside a setstate but the UI is still not updating.

I have the exact same issue in another view with the TabBarView, the child widgets don't update after a setstate and a change